# Why do we describe matrixes by m x n and not r x c?

Tags: matrices, notation

So whenever we want to describe a matrix by a number of rows and a number of columns, we write "$m \times n$".

Why is it that we don't call it a $r \times c$ matrix instead of $m \times n$? What do m and n stand for? Is this something some people decided 2000 years ago and now we're just stuck on it? It would make much more sense if it was $r \times c$ - then it is also easier for new students to remember (r for row, c for column).

[image]

Comment: Because usually *natural* numbers are symbolized with $m$ and $n$...

Comment: So a $2 \times 3$-matrix means: a matrix with 2 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: Yes I know, but why dont we call it r x c instead of m x n?? It would make much more sense. Because its m x n, its harder to remember what's rows and what's columns. Would be much easier if we all just agreed to use r x c

Comment: Maths is supposed to be a universal language: as handy as "r for row and c for column" might be in English, this will not make any sense for speakers of other languages.

Comment: I agree, but most people speak English anyway, what language is m x n useful for?? Edit: R x c would also be lovely for russians, so both English-speakers and russian-speakers would love it

Comment: The language of maths: it's designed to be neutral.

Comment: A problem that might occur with your notation is when you multiply two matrices. If the first one is $r \times c$, then the second one has to be$\dots$

Comment: An $m\times n$ matrix can be seen as a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$.  I would expect the language of linear transformations and the spaces $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$ were decided upon before the language of matrices came around and the variable names used were set to match... it is an $m\times n$ matrix rather than an $r\times c$ matrix *because* it was $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$ being talked about, not $\Bbb R^r$ and $\Bbb R^c$

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Idk why ppl are downvoting though, I was just wanting to know, and it was nowhere to find on the internet :''(

Comment: As for why $m$ and $n$, as alluded to already... "**n**umber" and "**n**atural" start with $n$ and $m$ is a nearby letter, so it is a commonly used variable name for natural numbers.  Similarly, $i$ and $j$ are common for their use to denote "**i**ndex" variables and $q$ and $r$ for rational numbers from the word "**q**uoziente" (*or similar words from other latin families*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a compelling reason not to speak of $r\times c$-matrices: matrices are not the fundamental object we're dealing with. Vector spaces and the linear maps between them are. Matrices are just a way to represent those maps, and the number of their columns is the dimension of the domain, and the number of their rows is the dimension of the codomain. So on a more fundamental level, $n$ and $m$ are the dimensions of two vector spaces, not the number of columns and rows of a matrix.